# Topic Iamtopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka, integration-testing

We do have kafka producer building application. I need to write integration test cases for the same. I tried to create a zookeeper and kafka intance using DockerImageName and embedded kafka classes. Its running fine if I am creating producer in same class where my zookeper and kafka is getting created. but when I am trying to trigger producer from another class its giving below error :

```
> 2020-08-21 22:53:27 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:755 [WARN]
> [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1
> (localhost/127.0.0.1:32772) terminated during authentication. This may
> happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed
> due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall
> blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3)
> Transient network issue. 2020-08-21 22:53:27
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1030 [WARN] [Producer
> clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:32772 (id: -1 rack:
> null) disconnected 2020-08-21 22:53:28
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:755 [WARN] [Producer
> clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:32772)
> terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the
> following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid
> credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka
> TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient
> network issue. 2020-08-21 22:53:28
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1030 [WARN] [Producer
> clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:32772 (id: -1 rack:
> null) disconnected java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic Iamtopic not
> present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```